# Customize horizontal positon of table within page

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment

I am using memoir package and I want to generally left align tables (In contrast to figures that should be centered). I am using the `hmisc` latex function which generates this float table code, but I didnt find a way to easily change/discard the center environment:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
...content...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I already tried the following:

```
\let\centering\relax
```

to generally disable centering. My idea is to selectively enable centering for figures. To achieve this I am trying to use the package `floatrow` but I without any success. Could somebody draft how to either selectively switch off or switch on centering. (Providing I am using the `hmisc` latex function to generate the table.)

Edit 1: Additional Question: Is there a way (and how) to disable centering (as mentioned using the `\let` command) but center a figure afterwards somewhere in the document ?

Answer (score 1):

The only mention I could find of `hmisc` is an `R` package. If you are using R it would have been helpful to say so. Strictly this is off topic for this site as it is an R programming question.

The manual for hmisc is here

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf

and on page 149 (or just search for center which is what I did) it says

```
center=c(’center’,’centering’,’none’),
```

so I assume you want `none`.

Comment: Actually I was hoping that there is a way to define a global setup that triggers this kind of positioning for table and figure floats separately.

Comment: but why get R to put in centering if you don't want it? You can go `\let\oldtable\table\def\table{\oldtable\let\center\flushleft\let\endcenter\endflushleft}` but that seems an odd thing to do.

Comment: because I have a lot of tables that are already generated using the default.

Comment: Thanks for the code to redefine the table. It works but it outputs the positioning option of the table environment like: [!h] and [!tbp] just above of each table.

Comment: sorry move `\oldtable` to be the last thing not the first thing in the definition of `\table`.